# Keeping figure just after text in Latex

Tags: floats

I am writing in Latex. I am new with it and need some help. I need to add figures. I can do it with the following code:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \includegraphics[width = 15cm]{figures/mlpStrSingle}
    \caption{MLP neural network for one single output node}
    \label{fig:mlp}
\end{figure}
```

However, if I use this the figure goes to the next page. I need it right after the text, then the next text should start. How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Simply do not use the floating environment `figure`, for the caption load package `caption` and use command `captionof{figure}` ... As usual here please make your code snippet compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: And for more explanation on how this all works, see [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017).

Comment: Be aware that LaTeX defines floating environments such as `figure`and `table` so it can place them in the best possible way according to its criteria. Forcing the placement may result in large white spaces in your document.

Comment: If you don't want your image to move away, you could use `\begin{center}\includegraphics[width = 15cm]{figures/mlpStrSingle}
    \captionof{figure}{MLP neural network for one single output node}
    \label{fig:mlp}
\end{center}`. You will need the `caption` package or this to work.

Comment: @leandriis thanks. that worked out